# JavaScript replace function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have posted a CodeIgniter code below, and in this code I am sending ajax calls to get transliteration of user input. Everything is working perfectly fine but at this line:

```
$("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>").val($("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>").val().replace(/(^[،\s]+)|([،\s]+$)/g, '')  );
```

I am trying to trim the value of input field but the value is not being trimmed and it remains as it is. Please tell what can be the issue?

**Code:**

```
<?php foreach($this->config->item('allowed_lang') as $code => $lang) { ?>
    $("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>").val('');
    for(i=0; i<all_values.length; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "https://www.google.com/inputtools/request?text="+all_values[i]+"&ime=transliteration_en_"+"<?php echo $code; ?>"+"&num=5&cp=0&cs=0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=jsapi&uv",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>").val( data[1][0][1][0] +"، "+ $("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>").val() );
            }
        });
        $("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>").val( $("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>").val().replace(/(^[،\s]+)|([،\s]+$)/g, '')  );        
    }
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Use `.trim()` instead of `replace(/(^[،\s]+)|([،\s]+$)/g, '')  )`

Answer (score 0):

Use `toString` before replace function like this:

```
$("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>").val($("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>").val().toString().replace(/(^[،\s]+)|([،\s]+$)/g, '')  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` method doesn't replace the expression's value 'in-place'. Use an assignment to get the replaced value. 
For example:

```
var string1;

string1 = $("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>")
           .val().replace(/(^[،\s]+)|([،\s]+$)/g, '');
$("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>").val(string1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because the Ajax is Asynchronous in JavaScript** .

Your success function will get start since get the response. But the request need time to get the response. So the program will skip the Ajax callback function and directly run next line of codes.

You can fix it easily like this :

```
for(i=0; i<all_values.length; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "https://www.google.com/inputtools/request?text="+all_values[i]+"&ime=transliteration_en_"+"<?php echo $code; ?>"+"&num=5&cp=0&cs=0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=jsapi&uv",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>").val( data[1][0][1][0] +"، "+ $("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>").val() );

                $("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>").val( $("#"+modal_field_prefix+"<?php echo $lang; ?>").val().replace(/(^[،\s]+)|([،\s]+$)/g, '')  );        
            }
        });
```

Also you can read this link to know all about the Asynchronous JavaScript.

https://www.codementor.io/aminmeyghani/learn-asynchronous-javascript-in-2018-fmbib9obw

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite strange.
`$("#"+modal_field_prefix+"")`

Do you forgot the literal string "" surround modal_field_prefix ? 
It must be 
`$("#" + "modal_field_prefix" + "")`